# Can't cleanup a zombie process whose parent is init

Tags: linux, kill, zombie-process

I have a zombie process:

```
$ ps aux | grep Zl
root      6641  122  0.0  0 0 ? Zl   08:57 371:10 [ovs_dpdk] <defunct>
```

And, its parent looks like `init`

```
$ pstree
init─┬─acpid
     ├─atd
     ├─cron
     ├─dbus-daemon
     ├─dnsmasq
     ├─6*[getty]
     ├─irqbalance
     ├─libvirtd───10*[{libvirtd}]
     ├─ovs_dpdk───{ovs_dpdk}               <==== here
     ├─rpc.idmapd
```

But, kill -9 does not kill him...

```
sudo kill -9 6641
```

I'm stumped here, any help?

Comment: This is more appropriate for [unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). But have you tried `kill -SIGKILL 6641`?

Comment: -SIGKILL doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot kill a zombie because it is already dead. :-)

Seriously, a zombie process has already exited, so there is nothing to kill. Its entry in the process table is hanging around until the parent that created the (now dead) child sees the exit status.

[Wikipedia (who else?) has a great discussion of this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process).

You can remove the process entry with SIGCHLD by telling its parent to reap the dead child:

```
kill -s SIGCHLD PPID
```

where PPID is the parent process ID. [ht the xmodulo folks](http://xmodulo.com/2012/06/how-to-find-and-kill-zombie-processes.html)

Comment: The real problem is that since the zombie process is using a kernel module as a user, the ref count in kernel module increases. The think I want to do is to unload the kernel module, but since the ref count is not 0, I can't do it. Except rebooting, what could I do?

Comment: Good question. [This link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11172/how-can-i-kill-a-defunct-process-whose-parent-is-init) says `init` is supposed to run `wait()` periodically to reap out zombies. If your system isn't doing so, it would seem rebooting is your only choice.

Answer (score 1):

A zombie is a process that has exited and is no longer running, but stays in the process table till it's parent "wait()s" for it.. to get it's exit status.  Kill the parent, or get it to wait on it's child.

Comment: and once the parent is dead, init (process 1) inherits it as a child, and init always waits for any child exiting.

Answer (score 0):

Zombie can't be clean up by Kill command. If it's a child process of **Init process (pid = 1)** then it should auto cleanup.

OR 
As init process is not cleaning up Just **Reboot System**.

if the Zombies got generated again then might be **code bug**. You need to look into code issue : as Parent is not waiting for getting the return exit code by child.

As a reference various example is quoted here [Generation and cleanup of Zombies n C](https://codar.club/blogs/generation-and-cleanup-of-linux-c-zombie-processes.html)  might be helpful.

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks for your time to review this. My one concerned is for reference I can use the link because with example reply will be too big.

Answer (score -1):

How do I kill zombie process?

You cannot kill zombies, as they are already dead. But if you have too many zombies then kill parent process or restart service.

You can kill zombie process using PID obtained from any one of the above command. For example kill zombie proces having PID 4104:
 kill -9 4104

reference - http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/killing-zombie-process.html

Comment: The what if the parent is init process?